# When I change the radius of a TextField, the rounded rectangle outline still remains inside the box

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I'm changing the radius of a text box, however when i do, I get the original outline inside the box like so:

[image: Outline inside rounded text box.]

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this. If anybody else runs in to this problem, all I did was change the border type in the properties inspector.